# Fancybox, resize Width in the latest Version

Tags: jquery, web, fancybox

I tried to resize the width of the fancybox after i click on a textbox to show the error but it didn't work.
I saw another post on SO but it's outdated i think.

```
$("a.fancy").fancybox({
        'width'             : 425,
        'height'            : 415,
        'autoDimensions'    : true,
        'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
        'type'              : 'iframe'
});
```

Inside the fancybox i have an iFrame with the sign up form where the user needs to sign up and i'm using a validation engine Posabsolute to show the error on the topRight but the fancybox is set to 425 and i need to resize it to 445 or 450 after an error occurs.

Anyone have an idea how i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a class to the element and change its style:

```
$(".fancy").addClass("errorClass");
```

Comment: mmm I didn't quite understand, what can i do with adding this class ? I need to resize the width of the fancybox and i'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: you can change the width of the element by adding this class, it depends on the context that error has occurred, and your error handler. you can change elements width easily by jQuery width() method;  http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
$('#fancybox-wrap, #fancybox-outer, #fancybox-content').css('width', 'auto');
$.fancybox.center();
```